# Error installing Python ibm-db driver on Linux

Tags: python-2.7, db2

I'm trying to install ibm_db driver in Linux for Python. I test the installation using import ibm_db. The installation was successful. When I test using 'import ibm_db' I get the following error:

ImportError: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ibm_db-2.0.3-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/ibm_db.so: undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS2_FromObject

Please help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

Please try installing the current version of the ibm_db driver (which at time of writing is 2.0.8a),  which you can do via:

`pip install "ibm_db==2.0.8a"`

You need the version of pip that matches your python version.